# Selecting Multiple values from one string in SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, substring

Hi All I am using Oracle 11. The requirement is to select only those records where we have the 'New York' and 'Dallas'. Please note that the order of the cities with the same record can change. so from the following record set i should only have two records (i.e. Rec # 3 and 5). Please note that the values coming in City are concatenated by using wm_concat function

```
Rec#    City
1   New York
2   Huston
3   New York;Dallas
4   Los Angles
5   Los Vegas;Dallas;San Dieago;New York
6   Huston;Chicago;Salt Lake City;Cleaveland
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote it on Postgres because oracle fiddle is wrong but should be the same

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e14de/8)**

```
SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE "City" LIKE '%New York%'
AND "City" LIKE '%Dallas%'
```

The problem is if you try search something like `'York'` can match partially  and will also find `'New York'` so you can fix like this

```
SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE "City" LIKE '%York%'; -- will find `New York`

SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE ';' || "City" || ';' LIKE '%;York%;'; -- correct solve
```

As @Egor suggest you can do it with a single `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE ';' || "City" || ';;' || "City" || ';' LIKE '%;Dallas;%;New York;%' ;
```

Comment: `select ... where ';'||city||';;'||city||';' like '%;New York;%;Dallas;%'`

Comment: I was already into my answer which allowed for a city that could be part of another city or occurred at the start/end of the string.  I'll delete my other comment if your example handles it.

Comment: @Gary_W Yes, its does.:) Both solutions

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - This is a way to use only one LIKE instead of two.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, I can see it now, wasnt easy to read at first :),

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I include your solution in my Fiddle, And yes, you need the double semicolon `;;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Oracle syntax, but something like this:

`Select columns where cities like "Dallas" and cities like "New York"`

Comment: That probably only find Rec#1, you need wildcards

Comment: AND means it would have to match both New York and Dallas, why would it match only rec#1 ?

Comment: check dantella and my answer. You need include wildcard `%` otherwise only will match the exact string

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where City like '%New York%Dallas%' or City like '%Dallas%New York%'
```

Comment: Can we do it using substring function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with REGEXP_LIKE where the city sought after could be at the start or end of the line also.  The regular expression means where the sought after city is proceeded by the start of the line or the delimiter and is followed by the delimiter or the end of the line.

```
with tbl(rec, city) as (
  select 1, 'New York' from dual union
  select 2, 'Huston' from dual union
  select 3, 'New York;Dallas' from dual union
  select 4, 'Los Angles' from dual union
  select 5, 'Los Vegas;Dallas;San Dieago;New York' from dual union
  select 6, 'Huston;Chicago;Salt Lake City;Cleaveland' from dual union
  select 7, 'Huston;Chicago;Salt Lake City;New York;York' from dual union
  select 8, 'York;Huston;Chicago;Salt Lake City' from dual  
)
select rec, city
from tbl
where regexp_like(city, '(^|;)York(;|$)')
and   regexp_like(city, '(^|;)New York(;|$)');
```

Comment: I include York to expand the sample, OP question need Dallas

Comment: Why are you matching just 'York'? I don't see any benefit to that according to what the OP is asking.

Comment: Testing a city name that could be part of another city name.  i.e. Match a city named "York" but not "New York". Always try to think of unexpected conditions in your test data.

Comment: I suspect the regexp_like is more expensive.  Do some timings on your data set and see if it matters.